# Android WebView Javascript error: "Uncaught TypeError" in API 15 - 18 but not 19+

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

In my Android project I'm using WebView to display a website that uses jQuery.  In reading this...

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html

...I understand that the WebView changed to be Chromium based at API 19.  The older version of WebView throws this error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Object javascript:TT.noop(); has no method 'click'
```

When my jQuery clicks on a link like this:

```
<a id="myID" href="javascript:TT.noop();"
 class="myClass" eventname="myEvent" 
 eventdata="myEventData"><label>Click The Link</label></a>

 <script>
    $("#myID").click();
 </script>
```

So, apparently, Chromium handles this ok but the WebView before API 19 doesn't.
Any ideas? I'd really like to support the older WebView.
Any tips would be appreciated!